# How to add Cloud CDN to GCP VM? Always no load balancer available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, cdn, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a running Web server on Google Cloud. It's a Debian VM serving a few sites with low-ish traffic, but I don't like Cloudflare. So, Cloud CDN it is.

I created a load balancer with static IP.

I do all the items from the guides I've found. But when it comes time to *Add origin to Cloud CDN,* no load balancer is available because it's "unhealthy", as seen by rolling over the yellow triangle in the LB status page: "1 backend service is unhealthy".

At this point, the only option is to choose *Create a Load Balancer.*

I've created several load balancers with different attributes, thinking that might be it, but no luck. They all get the "1 backend service is unhealthy" tag, and thus are unavailable.

---Edit below---

During LB creation, I don't see anywhere that causes the LB to know about the VM, except in cert issue (see below). Nowhere does it ask for any field that would point to the VM.

I created another LB just now, and here are those settings. It finishes, then it's marked unhealthy.

**Type**
HTTP(S) Load Balancing

**Internet facing or internal only?**
From Internet to my VMs

(my VM is not listed in backend services, so I create one... is this the problem?)

**Create backend service**

- Backend type: Instanced group
- Port numbers: 80,443
- Enable Cloud CDN: checked
- Health check: create new: https, check /

**Simple host and path rule**: checked

**New Frontend IP and port**

- Protocol: HTTPS
- IP: v4, static reserved and issued
- Port: 443
- Certificate: Create New: Create Google-managed certificate, mydomain.com and [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load balancer's unhealthy state could mean that your LB's healthcheck probe is unable to reach your backend service(Your Debian VM in this case).

If your backend service looks good now, I think there is a problem with your firewall configuration.

Check your firewall rules whether it allows healthcheck probe's IP address range or not.

Refer to the docoment below to get more detailed information.

[Required firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#firewall_rules)

Comment: thanks @kallusis369... see in my edit that the LB does not know about my VM, so I don't believe the problem is the healthcheck reaching the VM, it's higher up

Comment: @instamattic Did you try with a 'Instance group' when your LB creation step?? GCP LB can transfer traffic to 'instance group' only,  Not a single VM. But if you really want to use single vm backend, Consider unmanaged instance group.   https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service

Comment: thanks, I'm now closer to solving this. My prior instance was managed, and thus didn't have my VM in it. Now I have an unmanaged instance with the VM inside it. I can ping the LB from the VM. LB shows healthy. **Add origin to Cloud CDN** -> **Choose Load Balancer** still shows nothing... Do I need to point domain DNS to LB IP at this point?

Comment: If you checked Enable Cloud CDN at backend configuration, GCP automatically create your cloud cdn service already. check whether your backend service's cloud cdn enabled or not.

Comment: thanks @kallusis369. The CDN LB IP address now serves my test page on :80. Whoo! Port 443/https is throwing a ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH (Chrome) and SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP (FF) using my test subdomain. Naked IP also does this. I have a (Google managed) cert on the LB's Frontend IP:443 that is green/check for my test subdomain in the cert's Provisioning status. Commenting in/out the Letsencrypt cert at my test subdomain makes no difference. Frontend protocol has 2 entries for the IP, one :80 and one :443 w/cert mentioned previously. Googling now for answers to this.

Comment: Got the test domain working for https. I created a new Google Managed cert for that Frontend IP (test.domain.com), and removed the cert that was present (test.domain.com [green checkmarked], www.domain.com, domain.com) after running test.domain.com through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html and getting "Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server ". Thanks for all your input, @kallusis369.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)